# Sample C++ tests

Tags: c++, testing

I'm about to take a C++ test.  But I only get one crack at it to get over 85%.  If I don't push over that, then I don't get the job.

The problem with these tests are that they typically target **generic C++,** and depending on what libraries you use your definition of generic may differ.  STL and Boost may seem logical to some (and should be part of most) but I worked with MFC for years before ever using templates.  Why use >vector> when you've got access to CArray?  (retorical question)

If you've worked with dialogs you've not used `stdio`.  If you've worked with Borland products you've not used MFC.  If you've worked with Palm, you've not used the file system, and you've definitely not used `CFile`.

**OK, so here's the question...**

Given that I'd like to pass the 85%, I'm taking online tests of "generic" C++.  So... **Is there a place I could go to find tests?**  The more the better.  Correct answers are also good, either during or after the test. As long as I can learn from my mistakes.

EDIT:  If your answer doesn't have a link to a test, some C++ questions, or some interview questions... You missed the point of **Is there a place I could go to find tests?**

*Great example.. I've just found this question.

What does the following code fragment print?  `cout << setw(6) << setfill('#') << "Hello";` 

I've been coding for 9 years. And never used `cout`, `setw` or `setfill` once.  Not since university.*

Comment: I would be surprised if a C++ test requried knowledge of any C++ library except std::, at least without explicitly stating so upfront. Do you have reason to beleive they will?

Comment: Well.. std is my point.  If a test has < stack > then I'd be screwed. Same goes for string.  I've never used either.  But they are in there. I mean they're simple but if I've got 1 min to answer a question. I might not have enough time to "remember" how to use them. I'd like to take tons of tests.

Comment: The code you posted should print "Hello#" if I remember correctly, I usually have to use a book to get the iomanip sttuff correct.

Comment: I do highly recommend [Codility](https://codility.com/programmers/lessons/). It is used by several companies for coding sessions to check if an applicant does fit to the companies needs. They have a lot of tests you can try out to simulate such test and they give you an result how good you performed for each test. Definitely give it a try.

Answer (score 10):

Erase all the MFC from your head for now. Go pick up a book like [The C++ Programming Language](http://www.research.att.com/~bs/3rd.html), and try to learn the concepts front to back. You should be fine. If they are asking for more than this, I don't want to know what their definition of "generic" is.

Comment: Concur -- MFC may have its uses even in this day and age, but few would hold it up as the shining example of how best to use C++.

Comment: Didn't answer the question.  Not one mention of the word TEST. Sorry mate. Also, if your company uses MFC, then you use MFC, or you find a new job.  Agreed it's not the best, but best depends on a lot of variables.

Comment: You said "they specifically target generic C++". MFC != generic. Question was answered.

Comment: sorry john. The question was in bold. I'm not trying to learn c++.  I'm attempting to take tests to practice for an exam.  Agreed mfc!= generic, But I'm not looking for a def of generic.  I'm looking for tests.  Your answer didn't provide a test, or links to tests, or links to inteview questions.

Comment: PS.. c++ test that has no std and mostly mfc = http://www.acuit.com/_vti_bin/shtml.dll/Test_C++.htm  If that's the kind of test I get, and I'd not looked at it, I'd be screwed.

Comment: Reading a book will prepare you for an exam. My answer still stands. Just because you found one MFC test doesn't mean most C++ tests are about MFC. If you don't like my answer, vote it down. Simple as.

Comment: John.  Q:Where do I find a beer store?  A:If you chill your glass and eat you should be prepared for beer.  Q:I didn't ask how to prepare for beer.  Where do I find beer? A: it's a good way to prep for the beer.   Q:  Where do I find beer?  A: See my point.. didn't ask how to prep. Asked for tests.

Comment: oH come on.. they're fun john.  I like the comments part of this better.  Chatter between us is so limited as a group. The comments bring us together.  (i did vote it down).

Answer (score 6):

The few times I've been *"tested"* (well *"interviewed"*), folks were far more concerned with questions like:

- What is Object Oriented Programming?  OOA (analysis)?  OOD (design)?  UML?
- When should you inherit from a class?  When should a class be aggregated?
- What are virtual methods?  What are pure virtual methods?  What is the vtable?
- Sibling cast problem.  class C : public A, public B;  C c;  B * b = & c;  How to cast object b (type B*) to an A*?
- What does the stack look like as a simple program executes?
- Differences between heap/stack?
- How does new() differ from malloc()?
- etc.

There's lots of previous discussion on C++ interviewing questions here on StackOverflow and elsewhere:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240212/
what-is-the-difference-between-newdelete-and-mallocfree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240212/what-is-the-difference-between-newdelete-and-mallocfree)

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347793/
c-areas-you-look-for-during-interview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347793/c-areas-you-look-for-during-interview)

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365823/
what-kinds-of-interview-questions-are-appropriate-for-a-c-phone-screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365823/what-kinds-of-interview-questions-are-appropriate-for-a-c-phone-screen)

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/GuerrillaInterviewing3.html

**Just to add my two cents here:**  If they are looking for graphic details...  To see if you've memorized the entire C++ spec...   Well I know the economy stinks right now but it is improving, there are other jobs out there, and you **NEED** to find one of them.  Interviews are a two-way street.   If they are into nit-picking details, this is **NOT** a place you want to work.

Answer (score 5):

You might try Herb Sutter's book [Exceptional C++](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/xc++.htm); it contains items organized like questions and is, in my opinion, very clear and very well written. I don't know if it will be directly useful for the interview, but it makes you think about aspects of the language you had never considered before.

It's been a long time since I last visited it, but you might also try this site with interview questions: [geekinterview.com](http://www.geekinterview.com) - take a look in particular at [the C++ section](http://www.geekinterview.com/Interview-Questions/Languages/C-Plus-Plus).

All the best for your interview :)

Answer (score 4):

*What does the following code fragment print? cout << setw(6) << setfill('#') << "Hello";*

It prints the following sentence to standard output:

> Please do not work for us. We have no clue about what it means to be a
>   good software developer.

Answer (score 2):

I found these.

http://www.acuit.com/_vti_bin/shtml.dll/Test_C++.htm

http://www.acetheinterview.com/questions/cats/index.php/algorithm

http://www.faqs.org/faqs/C-faq/faq/

http://www.coolinterview.com/type.asp?iType=41

http://www.radiussg.com.au/Candidate%20Interview%20Guide.pdf

http://www.eecs.utoledo.edu/~ledgard/oop/left.html

Comment: Has anybody tried these? Feedback? I mean I can search for "C++ test" as well, but I don't want to go through a lot of crap (which I've just done). Are the above okay?

Answer (score 1):

Some questions in [FAQ's](http://www.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html) might work as tests.

Answer (score 1):

IF you are going to give tests for job then brainbench tests may help.
I guess C++ tests are free and you can get some idea of what kind of questions you can get.

Good luck for tests!

Answer (score 0):

During interviews I bother about the candidate being able to show me that he/she understands what he's/she's doing and that he's/she's leaning toward "modern" C++ (i.e. template intensive).

He/she also needs to understand some subtilities of the languages, but not the most arcane. I don't ask tricky question that are based on the oddities of the language. Why?

STL mastery is a pre-requisite. I see knowing nothing about Boost as a bad sign.

If I were to write a test, I would make it quite easy just to filter the really bad programmers that don't master the syntax and the logic of C++. I however prefer a one hour one-to-one interview to filter candidates.

If you find yourself fighting against a very hard written C++ test : run away.

I hope this helps.

Edit : if you *really* want tests and questions, check this out : http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/

Comment: Ed.. The problem is to get to the "conversation" part of the interview, I need to pass a test.  Your answer's got no links to tests, or interview questions.  I too prefer the 1hr 1on1.  But I can't get there without 85%  Got any links?

Comment: See.. case in point Ed. I know some fantastic c++ programers, some with 20 + years who've never heard of Boost. Some of them have written low level drivers, boot loaders.  Hardly amiture level work. Yet nothing about SLT or boost.  You define SLT&Boost as generic, and these ppl would fail your test.

Comment: 20 years of C++ experience and never heard of boost or stl? That's pretty odd! As for your 85%, I really think this is a bad sign for a recruitment process which was my main bullet point.

Comment: @baash05: I find it incredibly hard to believe that someone who has been programming in C++ for that long hasn't even heard about at least the STL.

Comment: Lack of exposure to STL/BOOST is far more common that you might think.  Jobs where you are overworked (working 7 days every week, >10 hours a day, + a 3 hour commute) do not encourage learning new tools.  If you are stuck with older compilers, template support is a nightmare.  It happens.

Comment: Well perhaps not hearing of SLT is odd, not working with it, on the other hand.  I've never met "in person" a c++ programmer who's used BOOST.  I've been asking all the ones I know. SLT and BOOST are really just another set of libs. While I admit some cool fetures I seldome ever knowingly use SLT.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few free tests [here](http://www.interqiew.com/tests?type=cpp) and they have explanation videos on youtube for a few of the questions.